# Cómo recorrer por partes un ArrayList<> en java?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

Cómo puedo hacer para recorrer por partes un ArrayList<>, osea si el ArrayList<> tiene 9 objetos, como hago para iterar sobre los tres primeros, y luego iterar sobre los otros 3 cuando lo desée, y así sucesivamente. Es para mostrar los resultados de una DB pero con un máximo de 3 elementos en la pantalla.

```
package com.example.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.model.*;

public class ArrayListController {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Person> al = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayListController.list(al);

}

public static void list(List<Person> list) {

    Person p1 = new Person();
    Person p2 = new Person();
    Person p3 = new Person();
    Person p4 = new Person();
    Person p5 = new Person();
    Person p6 = new Person();
    Person p7 = new Person();
    Person p8 = new Person();
    Person p9 = new Person();

    p1.setName("1");
    p2.setName("2");
    p3.setName("3");
    p4.setName("4");
    p5.setName("5");
    p6.setName("6");
    p7.setName("7");
    p8.setName("8");
    p9.setName("9");

    list.add(p1);
    list.add(p2);
    list.add(p3);
    list.add(p4);
    list.add(p5);
    list.add(p6);
    list.add(p7);
    list.add(p8);
    list.add(p9);

    //Recorro con con for normal todo el arraylist
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getName());
    }

    System.out.println("Separador");

    //Doy vuelta la lista con Collections y reverse.
    Collections.reverse(list);
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getName());
    }

    //      Cómo hago para recorrer de a tres en tres, osea una funcion que toco e imprime,
    //      luego vuelvo a tocar y me muestra los otros tres
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes definir un método `imprimirPersonas(list, startIndex, items)` el cual reciba como parámetros:

- `list`: listado de personas
- `startIndex`: índice a partir del cual se quiere empezar a imprimir
- `items`: cantidad de elementos que se quieren imprimir

El método sería algo así:

```
private static void imprimirPersonas(List<Person> personas, int startIndex, int items){
        // si los parámetros son validos comienzo a recorrer
        if(personas!= null && startIndex>=0 && startIndex<personas.size()){
            // recorro desde el indice inicial indicado mientras no haya llegado al final de la lista  ni haya impreso la cantidad deseada de elementos
            while(startIndex < personas.size() && items>0){
                //imprimo persona
                System.out.println(personas.get(startIndex).getName());
                // incremento el indice de recorrida
                startIndex++;
                // decremento la cantidad de items restantes a imprimir
                items--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Luego desde tu programa principal cada vez que invoques a esta función lo harás con `startIndex = 0, startIndex = 3, startIndex = 6 ..` etc

**Ejemplo**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Person p1 = new Person();
        Person p2 = new Person();
        Person p3 = new Person();
        Person p4 = new Person();
        Person p5 = new Person();
        Person p6 = new Person();
        Person p7 = new Person();
        Person p8 = new Person();
        Person p9 = new Person();
        Person p10 = new Person();
        Person p11 = new Person();


        p1.setName("1");
        p2.setName("2");
        p3.setName("3");
        p4.setName("4");
        p5.setName("5");
        p6.setName("6");
        p7.setName("7");
        p8.setName("8");
        p9.setName("9");
        p10.setName("10");
        p11.setName("11");



        list.add(p1);
        list.add(p2);
        list.add(p3);
        list.add(p4);
        list.add(p5);
        list.add(p6);
        list.add(p7);
        list.add(p8);
        list.add(p9);
        list.add(p10);
        list.add(p11);


        int items =3;
        int startIndex =0;
        while(startIndex  < list.size()){
            imprimirPersonas(list, startIndex, items); 
            startIndex += items;
        }
    }
```

**Salida**:

> 1 2 3
>
> 4 5 6
>
> 7 8 9
>
> 10 11